# Is there always at least one Markov number between $n$ and $n^2$, for $n > 2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I'm new to this site, so maybe it's a bad question, but I've been researching Markov numbers for a few days and I haven't found much research about them other than Wikipedia and a few sites. What I'm wondering is that there is always at least one Markov number between $n$ and $n^2$, for $n > 2$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please use TeX on this site. I edited your post to change n^2 to $n^2$ etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any odd indexed Fibonacci number is a Markov number, hence there is one between $n$ and $3n$ for any $n\geq 1$. It follows that there is one between $n$ and $n^2$ for any $n\geq 3$.

**P.S.** You can search for articles in [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/), which is a free database (and the oldest of its kind).

Answer (score 3):

GH has answered your question, but you might find the following sort of estimate to be of interest:
$$
\#\bigl\{ \text{Markoff numbers $m$ satisfying $m\le X$}\bigr\}
= C\cdot(\log X)^2 + O\bigl(\log X\cdot(\log\log X)^2\bigr)
$$
with an explicit $C>0$. See Zagier, D., On the number of Markoff numbers below a given bound. *Math. Comp.* **39** (1982), no. 160, 709-723. (Although this might be counting them with multiplicity, if by some chance the unicity conjecture were to be false in a major way.)